# What is histogram classifier and how to use it?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, histogram, bivariate, 2d

This question is about the assignment on my ML course..

I have been given two continuous data in a normal distribution and predict the values of both for class labels(m/f) in 2 steps:

1. build a histogram
2. use the histogram as a classifier to predict if m/f

i don't find any relevant package in python, R to do this.

Comment: Add the self study tag.

Answer (score 0):

What you call a histogram classifier, is within statistics known as a *multinomial classifier*. You can include one 'histogram variable', or more histogram variables. Several statisticians have published on this type of classifiers. One classic paper is that of Glick (1973).

A shorter introduction to the histogram classifier is found in the following link [Multinomial naive Bayes classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Multinomial_naive_Bayes). When each feature-histogram is treated independently of all the other ones, it is a naive Bayes classifier. For this type a classifier, the assumption of *conditional independence* applies. This means that all feature outomes are probabilistically independent, given the class label.

In practice, naive Bayes classifiers yield good discriminating performance and should always be used as a comparative benchmark when building a set of classifiers.

N. Glick. "Sample-Based Multinomial Classification," Biometrics,
Vol. 29, No. 2 (Jun., 1973), pp. 241-256.

Comment: thanks. i am going to use this explanation to study more and circle back to and understand this